# Gmap location with multilanguage site

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, location, google-maps

I installed [Gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) & [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) modules to display nodes on google map, every thing is setup as what i want but the problem is:

when changing the site language the nodes disappear from the map, the language prefix causing the problem.

How to show the google map with nodes in different language?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you found a fix for this?

Comment: i have not found any solution for it